# Android RealViewSwitcher shows view partially

Tags: android, swipeview

I've got the following problem. I'm using the RealViewSwitcher class (which extends ViewGroup and can be founded [here](http://marcreichelt.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-use-realviewswitcher-to-switch.html) ). I've got three views and swiping between them works well in both orientatons. However, when I change orientation dynamically (for example, I'm on the screen 1 in vertical view and change the orientation to horizontal) - the view is showing only partially (one third of the screen is first view, other two third - second view).

The code:

```
// my activity method
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
// ...
realViewSwitcher.setCurrentScreen(1);
// ...
}

// realViewSwitcher method
public void setCurrentScreen(int currentScreen) {
    mCurrentScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(currentScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
    scrollTo(mCurrentScreen * getWidth(), 0);
    invalidate();
}
```

UPD(10.09.2012): Added some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following snippet to your RealViewSwitcher Class,

```
public void orientationSnapToScreen(Context ctx)
        {
            Display display = ((WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
            int displayWidth = display.getWidth();

            mNextScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(getCurrentScreen(), getChildCount() - 1));
            final int newX = mNextScreen * displayWidth;
            final int delta = newX - getScrollX();

            mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, delta, 0, 0);
        }
```

and add the following method to your main activity from where you are calling the RealViewSwitcher class

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        realViewSwitcher.orientationSnapToScreen(this);
    }
```